# Showing dummy pic if picture it not available

Tags: php, html, css, image, font-awesome

I am trying to show a dummy image from [- Font awesome-](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-circle?style=solid) when the picture is not set.
You can see my code it shows the image if there is one but when there isn't one it needs to set the dummy pic from [awesomefont](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-circle?style=solid). tried pasting this `<i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>` in the else but that isn't working. can anyone please help me?

```
   <?php
      $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
      foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp){
        echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
            if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'])) { 
                echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'].'/'.$onderwerp['foto'].'" />';
            } else {
            }
            echo '<b><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie"> '.$onderwerp['onderwerpnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
            echo ' - ' . $onderwerp['voornaam'] . ' ' . $onderwerp['achternaam'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
```

**update**
this worked for me! I changed it a little with the `font-size`. The only problem I have is that it isnt aligned great. As you can see on the pic the text next to the picture on the first one is nice but the second and 3e are a little but lower? how to fix that?

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <?php

      $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
      foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp){
        echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
            if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'])) { 
                echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'].'/'.$onderwerp['foto'].'" />';
            } else {
                echo '<i style="font-size: 2.5em;" class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>';
            }
            echo '<b><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie"> '.$onderwerp['onderwerpnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
            echo ' - ' . $onderwerp['voornaam'] . ' ' . $onderwerp['achternaam'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
```

[how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbVFq.png)

Comment: Seems like it's your third account?

Comment: @u_mulder maybe but maybe I made the **one** other account with a temp mail :# but you know how to solve this?

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Well if I add  `< i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>` to the `else` it wont show me the picture

Comment: `'assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id']` might be there but not `$onderwerp['foto']`, have you checked its hitting the else?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the question is almost answered. maybe you can help me with the last bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing the required js file that's why it's not showing.

[**Getting Started**](https://fontawesome.com/get-started)

**Try:**

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <?php

      $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
      foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp){
        echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
            if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'])) { 
                echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'].'/'.$onderwerp['foto'].'" />';
            } else {
                echo '<i style="font-size: 6em;" class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>';
            }
            echo '<b><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie"> '.$onderwerp['onderwerpnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
            echo ' - ' . $onderwerp['voornaam'] . ' ' . $onderwerp['achternaam'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: O wauww.... I did not include that one... thanks! is there a way to make the pic bigger tho?

Comment: Updated the code. Just edit the `style` attribute, modify `font-size:`

Comment: thanks mate! I updated the question and still got a small problem as you can see there? any hints/tricks/tips on this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can put the font icon in else part and it should work perfectly.
I think your if statement isn't allowing you to goto else. just update the if condition like this:

```
$foto = '/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$onderwerp['klant_id'].'/'.$onderwerp['foto'].' 'images/userphoto/1/2/2/59874a886a0356abc1_thumb9.jpg';
if(file_exists($foto)) {
    echo '<img class="img-circle" src="'.$foto.'" />';
}
else{
 echo '<i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>'
}
```

For your second problem: 
You can write CSS class and use it in the parent, in your case it'll be `<div class="well align-children">` :

```
.align-children{
   line-height: 40px; /* depending on the size of your icon */
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can use the styling on html document with this:

```
<style>
.align-children{
   line-height: 40px; /* depending on the size of your icon */
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Ye this worked for me! thanks! can you look at the question again updated it a little

Comment: I guess you need to align the icon and text vertically. just apply the CSS to the items inside the 'well' div.

Comment: Is there no way to do it in the html document?

Comment: Yes! by using the style tag.